# Highlight Multiple Table Cells at Once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two tables side-by-side on my web page. When a mouse hovers over a cell on the first table or second table (for example cells(2,5)), i would like to highlight both first table's cell(2,5) and the second table's cell(2,5) at the same time. I've tried it with Css but i think its impossible to do it just with Css.

Comment: Can you add a working snippet demonstrating the issue?

Comment: I've no working snippet, i can hover just only one table but its not my point.

Comment: Yeah, It's impossible with css if two tables have the same element level without some use of JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do with some jQuery codes to get the magic, please check my snippet

```js
$('table td').hover(function(){
  // Highlight
  var curentEl = $(this);
  var outerEl = curentEl.closest('.outer');
  var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
  var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
  outerEl.find('table').each(function() {
    $(this).find('tr:eq('+ row +')' + ' ' + 'td:eq('+ col +')').addClass('hover');
  });
}, function() {
  //Removing Highlight when mouse out
  $(this).closest('.outer').find('.hover').removeClass('hover');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}

table:nth-child(2) {
 margin-left: 5%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

td.hover {
 border-color: red;
 background: #ddd;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>
<div class="outer">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i want to do. Thank you so much!